# Fill a column with a long formula VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to make a command button to fill a column with a long formula in Excel. 
Here is the formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$4,'Template Ideas'!D2))=TRUE,VLOOKUP('Tagging Inputs'!$C$4,'Tagging Inputs'!$B$12:$C$38,2,FALSE),""),""),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$4,'Template Ideas'!D2)),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$5,'Template Ideas'!D2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$6,'Template Ideas'!D2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$7,'Template Ideas'!D2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$8,'Template Ideas'!D2))))=TRUE,"; ",""),IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$5,'Template Ideas'!D2))=TRUE,VLOOKUP('Tagging Inputs'!$C$5,'Tagging Inputs'!$B$12:$C$38,2,FALSE),""),""),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$5,'Template Ideas'!D2)),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$6,'Template Ideas'!D2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$7,'Template Ideas'!D2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$8,'Template Ideas'!D2))))=TRUE,"; ",""),IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$6,'Template Ideas'!D2))=TRUE,VLOOKUP('Tagging Inputs'!$C$6,'Tagging Inputs'!$B$12:$C$38,2,FALSE),""),""),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$6,'Template Ideas'!D2)),OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$7,'Template Ideas'!D2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$8,'Template Ideas'!D2))))=TRUE,"; ",""),IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$7,'Template Ideas'!D2))=TRUE,VLOOKUP('Tagging Inputs'!$C$7,'Tagging Inputs'!$B$12:$C$38,2,FALSE),""),""),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$7,'Template Ideas'!D2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$8,'Template Ideas'!D2)))=TRUE,"; ",""),IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Tagging Inputs'!$C$8,'Template Ideas'!D2))=TRUE,VLOOKUP('Tagging Inputs'!$C$8,'Tagging Inputs'!$B$12:$C$38,2,FALSE),""),""))
```

I've been using this format for the command button

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Range("AD2").Formula = ""
Range("AD2", "AD" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Something tells me if you showed some data and what you trying to accomplish with the data we could propose a smaller formula.  Also FWIW all the `=TRUE` are not needed.  It is understood if it is true it does the first.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
lrow = Range("AD2", Range("AD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
Range("AD2:AD" & lrow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE("......)"
```

Watch your qoutes `"` They turn into double qoutes.